# Does setting a variable to empty list in Python reset the variable?

Tags: python

Here's the scenario, there's a nested list called **board**, and it is passed into the function, and I want to do some modification to the content to the list.

However, during the process, I found out that by assigning the variable to an empty list actually does something weird and any modifications on the **board** list does not affect the original **board** outside the function. Here's what I mean:

(It doesn't matter what the function does specifically)

This is modifyiing a particular slot in the list, and it works and **does affect** the original board.

```
def move_up(board):
    board[1][2] = '.'
```

This is fine also since appending technically is modifying the list, this **affects** the original board too.

```
def move_up(board):
    board.append(['.', 'F', '*', 'F', '.'])
```

This, however, doesn't work. This does not affect the original board, and I'm wondering why. The **board** variable shows gray, it almost feels like by doing =[], it is resetting the variable to something else, a new object, but I'm not really sure why.

```
def move_up(board):
    board = []
    board = [[1,2],[3,4]]
    board[1][1] = 5
```

Or, is this something with the scope? Please explain how this works in Python, thanks!

Comment: Don't post screenshots, copy and paste your code.

Comment: Yes it has to do with scope, you can read about it in any good tutorial

Comment: Removed screenshots.

Comment: Variables and assignment don't work the way you're thinking. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I believe I get it a bit now. By doing 'board = []', I'm creating a new object called 'board', and any modification done is made to this newly created object.

Comment: I thought it won't let you do that since the passed in argument is called the same name, hmmm guess I learned.

Comment: You're creating a new object, and binding the name `board` to it. That's slightly different from creating an object named `board`. If you did `foo = board` on the next line, both `foo` and `board` would reference that same new object, but the object wouldn't be *named* `foo` or `board`.

Comment: @yyin: Nope, Python lets you stomp most names. You can (but shouldn't) name shadow built-in functions, not just local names. If you do `str = 'abc'`, until you leave that scope or do `del str`, you can't call the `str` constructor, because you've shadowed it with your local variable.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks, do you know if this works the same in Java?

Comment: Thank you all for helping, appreciated!

Comment: @yyin: It's similar in Java, but the requirement that you declare a variable with a static type, and the fact that functions aren't first-class objects means you don't usually run into it. It also helps that Java tends to use verbose names for classes that you'd rarely consider using as variable name. That said, IIRC (my Java is stale) if you have an argument `List<int> x`, and inside your function, you do `x = new ArrayList<int>();`, you'll be rebinding `x` in exactly the same way; you'll lose the reference to the caller passed argument entirely.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Cool, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the indented block of `move_up`, "board" is the *local* name given to the argument.  There may be an object named "board" somewhere else in your program or there may not be.  You wouldn't expect Python to hunt it down and modify it for you, nor would you want it to.  Your function is exactly equivalent to this one:

```
def move_up(x):
    x = []
    x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
    x[1][1] = 5
```

Lists have a function named `clear` that removes all the elements from the list without creating a new object, and a function named `extend` which appends to the list element by element.

```
def move_up(x):
    x.clear()
    x.extend([[1,2], [3,4]])
    x[1][1] = 5
```

will do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I do have another question: since you used `.clear()` to make sure not to generate another object, why not just use `.append()` afterwards instead of `.extend()`?

Comment: I do realize that they work differently, but based on the task I want to achieve, I can pick one of them and it won't mess with the scope, right?

Comment: `append` and `extend` both modify the array itself so they don't change the scoping behavior.  The only difference is that `append` adds one object to the end of the list, and `extend` adds multiple objects one at a time (the argument of `extend` must be iterable).

Comment: Yes, I see it now, appreciated!